# Log4j2 log file not created

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

For a spring-boot application I'm trying to set up a log4j2 logger that will write the logs into a few sperate files, but the logs are only written to the console, I've checked my user_dir to make sure I'm not looking in the wrong location as well.

This is the code that should write the test logs:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    UsersService userService;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(UsersController.class);
    @PostMapping("CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword")
    public void createUserWithEmailAndPassword(@RequestParam String userName, @RequestParam String password, @RequestParam String email, HttpServletResponse response) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        logger.info("creating a new user");
        if(userService.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userName, password, email))
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
        else{
            logger.error("failed on creating a new user");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_EXPECTATION_FAILED);
        }

    }
}
```

this is my log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="FileAppender" ref="infoAppender" fileName="info-${date:yyyyMMdd}.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
        <File name="FileAppender" ref="errorAppender" fileName="error_warn-${date:yyyyMMdd}.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="errorAppender"/>
        </Root>
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="infoAppender" level="info"/>
    </Loggers>

    <Properties>
        <!--LINUX LOG DIRECTORY-->
        <Property name="logDirLinux">/storage1/user/logs/folderName/</Property>

        <!--WINDOWS LOG DIRECTORY-->
        <Property name="logDirWindows">C:\\logs\\</Property>

    </Properties>

</Configuration>
```

this is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.Itamarled'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'){
        exclude group : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'){
        exclude group : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that spring-boot couldn't recognize the log4j2.xml file because of the files structure.

The file has to be located directly in src/main/resources

Answer (score 2):

add a properties tag in to your XML file and then define your path to save your log file:

```
<Properties>
    ...

    <!--LINUX LOG DIRECTORY-->
    <Property name="logDirLinux">/storage1/user/logs/folderName/</Property>

    <!--WINDOWS LOG DIRECTORY-->
    <Property name="logDirWindows">D:\\logs\\folderName\\</Property>

</Properties>
```

Comment: I've added these properties and the result is still the same

Comment: would you update your question with the new config?

Answer (score 0):

From [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging#log4j2-configuration-logging),

spring default not using log library other than `Logback`,

to use log4j2, need to first exclude `Logback` from our dependencies.

So I choose to use `Logback` in spring, it is default no extra setting.